# Linear algebra proof differentiable functions with same rank

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose  $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $g: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are differentiable in the open sets $U\subseteq {R}^{m}$,  $V \subseteq {R}^{n}$ and $(g \circ f)(x)=x$ for all $x \in U$. Let $y=f(x)$. Prove the linear transformations  $f'(x):{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ y $g'(y):{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} $ hvae the same range.

From the hypothesys i can use tthe chain rule and see that since $(g \circ f)(x)=x$ for all $x \in U$ then $Dg(f(x))Df(x)=I_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$. Let $A=Dg(f(x))$ and $B=Df(x)$ so that $AB=I_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$ that means $A$ has a right inverse so it must be surjective, then rank of $A$ is $m$. Is this correct, what else can i say about $B$?

Comment: $B$ is injective, so $rank(B) = m$.

Comment: Why $B$ is injective?  if i choose  an element in it's kerner, why it must be $x=0$?

Comment: You have $AB = I$. If $Bx = 0$, then $x = ABx = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from $AB=I_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$ we get $rank(A)=m$.

Furthermore we have $B^TA^T=I_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$. This gives $rank(B^T)=m$, hence $rank(B)=m.$